# How to Configure availability set on azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, configuration, load-balancing

I am a newbie.I want to implement availability set/load balancer in azure vm which is for ubuntu webserver.I have implemented a rails website on it ..but while doing so am getting stuck.
I have created a service and have allocated the services to two virtual machine.

Now in the dashboard of the service i am getting two virtual machines..However both the endpoints for http are configured on port 80 hence giving a mismatch.
SSH DETAILS will be different.

Also on the virtual machine dashboard the http is not configured,hence giving issues.

Am not very sure about how load balancing should be configured for azure.

I went through this link but am getting very confused:-
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetupALoadBalancedWebFarmOfVirtualMachinesLinuxOrOtherwiseOnWindowsAzureCommandLine.aspx

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both servers should be configured the same... same HTTPS/TLS keys for https, same websites/api services... you then point external ports 80 to 80, and 443 to 443... Azure takes care of the load balancing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Avaiablity set are nothing but letting the azure know that your two VM are performing same job and you want atleast one to be up in case of downtime.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

What happens is when you provide the same availablity set to 2 VM then azure knows that they are having common task. So it will update one by one and don't down both at a time. Also Once you give availablity set then ports are common between VMs. i.e you can use 1433 on VM one then you can't 1433 on other one.

Load balancing is nothing but for improved performance request will navigate to either VM.